# Why does my CSS positioning appear different on Mac OS

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, macos

I am working on this website (http://www.kronofiles.com) and have encountered an issue when I load the page on a Mac. The issue is that all the content of the central body is positioned higher than it should be. I have tested multiple times on Windows with different computers, screen resolutions, and browsers but all have the same correct look on Windows machines. When I tested on Mac the screen resolution was`1366x768` on Google chrome and Safari. I am wondering if margins/padding could be causing this or if I will just have to send a different version of the site to a Mac machine. The HTML and CSS for the website are posted below on JSfiddle.

JSFiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/HeyItsProdigy/2RHuu/

Comment: Try validating your code first. You'll see errors like using the `<center>` tag.

Comment: @j08691 I just validated this and the only errors I receive are errors regarding the center tag.

Comment: I had a friend of mine test it on Mac OSX Mavericks and he used Safari  and Chrome. Both are fully updated.

Comment: _“the only errors I receive are errors regarding the center tag”_ – don’t what validator you used, but the official one from the W3C f.e. [also complains about your use of text inside an unordered list](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kronofiles.com%2F&charset=utf-8).

Comment: Could that be a possible cause of the false positioning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `Strict` settings

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

This will force you to follow rules that will apply to most browsers when you use the W3C validation.

Comment: How would this change anything?

Comment: i just ran a validation using `W3C CSS validation` on your site and received the following report: `Sorry! We found the following errors (35)` Using `Strict` in your `DOCTYPE` and correcting all the errors that appear after doing a `W3C CSS validation` will help with cross platform and cross browser